# Use c# model property in navigation property FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure the loading of the navigation property `Product.ProductGroup` with EF using following model:

```
internal class Code
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

```
internal class Product
{
    public int ProductNr { get; set; }

    public string ProductGroupCode { get; set; }

    public string ProductGroupCodeType => "PRD_GRPCD";

    public Code ProductGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Note that with the DB I'm working with, the `CodeType` (`"PRD_GRPCD"`) is not available in the DB and I can't add it. So it is only known in code

Here's the EF configuration for both entities, using the fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Code>(ConfigureCode);
    builder.Entity<Product>(ConfigureProduct);

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}

private static void ConfigureProduct(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("v_Product");

    builder.HasKey(product => product.ProductNr);

    builder.Ignore(product => product.ProductGroupCodeType);

    builder.HasOne(product => product.ProductGroup)
           .WithMany(code => code.Products)
           .HasForeignKey(product => new {product.ProductGroupCode, product.ProductGroupCodeType});
}

 private static void ConfigureCode(EntityTypeBuilder<Code> builder)
 {
     builder.ToTable("v_Code");

     builder.HasKey(code => new {code.Type, code.Value});
 }
```

I've expected that ignoring the property with `builder.Ignore(product => product.ProductGroupCodeType)` (see [Included and excluded properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties)) would allow me to execute this join but I get exceptions from EF:

- With `public string ProductGroupCodeType => "PRD_GRPCD";`: System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'Product.ProductGroupCodeType' and the property does not have a setter.
- With `public string ProductGroupCodeType { get; set; } = "PRD_GRPCD";`: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ProductGroupCodeType'.

I'm using EF core 5.0.15 (as I have to be backwards compatible with a netcoreapp3.1)

What am I doing wrong? Respectively, how can I specify the join in DB without having the value of the code type available in the product?

[edit] I've verified that when using `public string ProductGroupCodeType { get; set; } = "PRD_GRPCD";`, `ProductGroupCodeType` is part if the select, even when it is being configured as ignored.

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [v].[ProductNr], [v].[ProductGroupCodeType], [v].[ProductGroupCode]
FROM [v_Product] AS [v]
WHERE [v].[ProductNr] = @__productNr_0',N'@__productNr_0 int',@__productNr_0=61543
```

Comment: are you using ef code first with **existing** mismatching database?

Comment: You can't (yet). EF Core supports only relationships which can be represented with enforced physical FK constraints in relational database. Weak and logical relationships like the one you are asking for are not supported. Hence you cannot map/use navigation properties.

Comment: This feature would have come in handy in my scenario. I've fixed it by plugging a view on top of the table and adding a column holding this constant value.